# cannot load data from sqlite in navigation drawer fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

In my app i am using Navigation drawer and also sqlite database to display data from sqlite in the fragments.When i click on one of the navigation element i.e Search hospitals it should load data from the db but then the app flashes "unfortunately app was closed".

Below is the code of the fragment,

```
public class SHospitals extends Fragment {

private hospitalDBadapter dbhelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shospitals, container, false);

    dbhelper = new hospitalDBadapter(getActivity());
    dbhelper.open();
    dbhelper.deleteallhospitals();
    dbhelper.insertsomehospitals();
    Cursor cursor = dbhelper.fetchallhospitals();

    String[] columns = new String[] { hospitalDBadapter.KEY_HOSP,
            hospitalDBadapter.KEY_ADD, hospitalDBadapter.KEY_CONT };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.hospital, R.id.address, R.id.contact, };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.hospitalinfo, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    final ListView listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String hospital_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("hosp_name"));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), hospital_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    EditText myfilter = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.filter);

    myfilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return dbhelper.fetchhospitalsbyname(constraint.toString());
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}}
```

and this is my databasehelper class,

```
public class hospitalDBadapter {

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_HOSP = "hosp_name";
public static final String KEY_ADD = "hosp_Add";
public static final String KEY_CONT = "hosp_cont";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hospitals_dbs";
private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "hospitals_tables";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TAG = "hospitalDBadapter";
public final Context ourcontext;
private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_HOSP
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ADD + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_CONT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public hospitalDBadapter(Context c) {
    ourcontext = c;
}

public hospitalDBadapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourcontext);
    mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDBHelper != null) {
        mDBHelper.close();
    }
}

public boolean deleteallhospitals() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int donedelete = 0;
    donedelete = mDB.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null, null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(donedelete));
    return donedelete > 0;
}

public void insertsomehospitals() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    createhospital("Lilavati Hospital", "Peddar Road", "6541324532");
    createhospital("Sion Hospital", "A B Road", "6451235478");
    createhospital("Dayaben Hospital", "S P Road", "4132456787");
    createhospital("ABC Hospital", "P D Road", "8451295421");
    createhospital("DEF Hospital", "D S Road", "9832151231");

}

private long createhospital(String hosp_name, String hosp_Add,
        String hosp_cont) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_HOSP, hosp_name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADD, hosp_Add);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CONT, hosp_cont);

    return mDB.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public Cursor fetchallhospitals() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_HOSP, KEY_ADD, KEY_CONT }, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor fetchhospitalsbyname(String string) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.w(TAG, string);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        mCursor = mDB.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_HOSP,
                KEY_ADD, KEY_CONT }, null, null, null, null, null);

    } else {
        mCursor = mDB.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_HOSP, KEY_ADD, KEY_CONT }, KEY_HOSP + " like '%"
                + string + "%'", null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

}

plz.help me out.

This is my LogCat

```
02-19 08:54:15.059: W/dalvikvm(2013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aefba8)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013): Process:    com.beproject.pocketdoctor, PID: 2013
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at  com.beproject.pocketdoctor.SHospitals.onCreateView(SHospitals.java:45)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at  android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at  android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-19 08:54:15.069: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Does your app throw any exception (Logcat)?

Comment: no, it does nothing. the app simply crashes down

Comment: yeah it throws nullpointerException, @Christopher.

Comment: Then try to fix the NPE or append your log.

Comment: appended the log @Christopher

Comment: `ListView listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv1);` -> `ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv1);` (same goes for the edittext.) You obviously can't call `getView` when you haven't yet returned what the view is going to be.

Comment: check you "SHospitals.java:45" this line. and also do as said by  @njzk2.

Comment: yeah ,rootView worked for me. Thanks a lot. @njzk2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line looks strange with the comma as last entry in your array:

```
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.hospital, R.id.address, R.id.contact, };
```

Second, I guess this is not working:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lv1);
```

Should be

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
```

Comment: `this line looks strange with the comma as last entry in your array`. no. this is actually perfectly valid and is equivalent to omitting the last coma.

Comment: @Christopher ,It worked for me, Thanks a lot for helping me in this.Instead of using getView() i used rootVIew . Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: @njzk2 I know that this line was valid code. But I do not see any benefit? Can you give me a use case?

Comment: @Christopher: I usually appreciate this thing when I have long arrays (works with enums too) and I am writing/debugging/fidgeting with values. I usually place one value on a separated line, and therefore I can comment or delete any line (including the last one) or add a line at any point (including at the end) without worrying about having correctly placed the coma.